# Differentiate full stop from decimal values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm working on a formula that checks a cell for a "£" sign, then checks the value after it. If the value is anything other than a rounded value, e.g. "£30" or "£30.00", it would be an error.

My problem is, the text has a full stop after the decimal value. This results in the 'DECIMAL' value being returned. How do I not count £30. as an error.

Below is the formula as input through VBA

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(""."",LEFT((RIGHT(RC[-2],LEN(RC[-2])-SEARCH(""£"",RC[-2]))),SEARCH("" "",(RIGHT(RC[-2],LEN(RC[-2])-SEARCH(""£"",RC[-2])))))))=FALSE,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("".00"",LEFT((RIGHT(RC[-2],LEN(RC[-2])-SEARCH(""£"",RC[-2]))),SEARCH("" "",(RIGHT(RC[-2],LEN(RC[-2])-SEARCH(""£"",RC[-2])))))))=FALSE,"""",""DECIMAL""),"""")
```

Comment: With such a complex formula, I think that anyone would prefer that you explain more precisely what you want to achieve and provide you with a working formula instead of trying to fix this one. The problem with formulas is, in general, their *readability*...

Comment: Basically, look for a £ within a cell (they are text messages that are sent out, but they cannot contain decimal values, i.e. £30 is fine, £30.00 is fine but £30.56 is not) My problem is, where they input the value, it is followed by a full stop as it is the end of the sentence.

I can get the formula to work (as in, it shows an error on any incorrect values) but it also returns true if people omit the decimal point entirely. E.g. £30.00. would be fine, but £30. (full stop at the end) currently returns an erro where it shouldnt

Comment: Can you post some sample data too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a User Defined Function that should do what you want.  It looks for a substring that starts with the € currency sign and then some number of digits.  If there is a dot following, it looks at the dot and the next two digits (or nothing if no digits).  If the value of that sequence is zero, then the function returns `TRUE`, else `FALSE`

Obviously, you can modify this to return whatever you want, or use it within an `IF` formula on the worksheet.

Note that it will only work on strings, and not on values formatted as currency.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function ValidCurrency(S As String) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPattern As String = "€\s*\d+(\.\d{2})?"

ValidCurrency = False
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPattern
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ValidCurrency = (MC(0).submatches(0) = 0)
    End If
End With

End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly @Ron-rosenfeld , very succinct! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string you want to check is in `F1`, I think you could do something like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("£",F1)),IF(TRIM(MID(F1&"00",FIND("£",F1)+1,5))="30.00",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

This:

1. assumes the `£` number you want to inspect is the first occurrence of that "£" character in the string.
2. Assumes that an occurrence of "£30." would occur at the end of the sentence, as you assert in your comments above.

But perhaps you left out some details for examples in which it won't work.

---

For your follow up question, the following would work for all two-digit whole number values (10 thru 99).  Note that I'm comparing the value in the string to its `ROUND()`ed value to see if the two match, and thus make sure there's nothing after the decimal. This should be enough for you to adapt it further on your own if you need to cover a broader range of values, but at this point, I think I've answered your original question and then some.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("£",F1)),IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(F1&"00",FIND("£",F1)+1,5)))=ROUND(VALUE(TRIM(MID(F1&"00",FIND("£",F1)+1,5))),0),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to look for any monetary value? For example it could be any value - here are two seperate examples - a string containing "£73.10" would fail, "£103.00" would pass, "£25" SHOULD pass, but there is a full stop after it that is being counted as a decimal point currently there is only one instance of a monetary value per string

Comment: Atlernatively, you could adapt this pattern matcher in VBA (https://excel.tips.net/T007348_Extracting_a_Pattern_from_within_Text.html).  But I usually prefer to do as much in built-in formulas as possible w/out resorting to VBA.  Good luck!